# AutoMapper ignore member failing when mapping with Type objects

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper

Using AutoMapper, I'm trying to map two types that I pull from two different assemblies via reflection. However, when working with Types, I am unable to get the .ForMember() method to ignore any members that I specify. The regular lambda syntax does not compile because the member name is not found on the `Type` type of the class. Passing in a string of the member allows compilation, but still does not ignore the member. Using config.AssertConfigurationIsValid() shows that this is an invalid configuration.

```
class ExampleSchema
{
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

class ExampleDto
{
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public int Weight {get; set;}
}
```

In the code that reflects over the above assemblies:

```
var schemaType = typeof(ExampleSchema);
var dtoType = typeof(ExampleDto);

// This will throw
// Cannot convert lambda expression to string because it is not a delegate type
cfg.CreateMap(schemaType, dtoType)
    .ForMember(dest => dest., opt => opt.Ignore());

// Hard-code cringing aside, this still does not filter out the member
cfg.CreateMap(schemaType, dtoType)
    .ForMember("Weight", opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Is this a bug in AutoMapper or am I just using the method incorrectly?

Comment: I did not see any problem with your code (except the part with the lambda, but that is obvious). I also tested it and it was no problem to map ExampleSchema instance to ExampleDto instance.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: The very latest 5.1.1

Comment: I am on latest, 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small test to see what is happening

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        var schemaType = typeof(ExampleSchema);
        var dtoType = typeof(ExampleDto);

        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap(schemaType, dtoType)
                .ForMember("Weight", conf => conf.Ignore());
        });

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var schema = new ExampleSchema { Age = 10 };

        var dto = mapper.Map<ExampleDto>(schema);

        Assert.AreEqual(dto.Age, 10);
        Assert.AreEqual(dto.Weight, 0);
    }
```

And it is green. You don't even need to configure anything.

Comment: Add the line `mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`

Comment: @Dagrooms Please test **this** code by yourself. I did not get any exceptions, warnings, ... Even with the validation check.

Comment: I understand that the mapping may work in this case, but the validation check fails when calling `mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`

Comment: I edited the test above and it is still green.And your truth -- without additional configuration AutoMapper throws validation exception in this line.

Answer (score 0):

Make your properties public and use

```
cfg.CreateMap<ExampleSchema, ExampleDto>()
```

. Then you will have an access to ForMember overload that accepts Expression parameter.

Comment: You must not understand my example. I am reflection over an assembly and getting the `Type` definitions for these types to map. I must use the `Type` definitions to perform this mapping programmatically. I can't use `CreateMap<ExampleSchema, ExampleDto>()`, it has to be `CreateMap(schemaType, dtoType)`.

Comment: Ok. But what does it mean "does not filter out the member"? You are seeing an exception or what?

Comment: AssertConfigurationIsValid fails.